# Recursively Searching in a Tree

Tags: ruby, recursion, tree

I'm working with the Stanford Parser in ruby and want to search for all nodes of a tree with a particular label name.
This is the recursive method i have coded so far

```
def searchTreeWithLabel(tree,lablename,listOfNodes)
  if tree.instance_of?(StanfordParser::Tree)
    if tree.lable.toString == lablename then
      listOfNodes << tree
    else
      tree.children.each { |c| searchTreeWithLabel(c, lablename, listOfNodes)}
    end
  end
  listOfNodes
end
```

i want the method to return a list of Tree nodes that have the label as labelname

Comment: i tried it in irb...and it just quits, no error message

Comment: @charudatta: You actually *called*  it in irb?  Or did you just put in the function definition?

Comment: called it...parsed a sentence using a lexicalized parser, assigned the o/p to a variable and run the method. the method defn is in a .rb file...i just 'required' it

Comment: @charudatta: What did it return?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar `StanfordParser` but I imagine you need to take the descent part of the traversal out of the inner conditional and always do it.

Also, did they really implement a `toString` method? Seriously?  It's not `.to_s`? I mean, I enjoyed Java, before I found Ruby... :-)

Comment: they did not implement a toString, the method is being called on a Tree instance which is actually a java instance available in ruby via the Ruby java bridge

Comment: Heh, I did figure there was a reasonable explanation, it was just funny to see...

Answer (score 0):

my original code was correct but ruby was having some problem with the

```
if tree.lable.toString == lablename then
```

statement, turns out tree.value works as well, so now i'm checking

```
if tree.value == lablename then
```

and it works.